# Unable to redirect airflow from floor to defroster, etc.in 2006 Cobalt

Tags: chevrolet, ac, hvac, cobalt

I replaced the heater / AC control module, but the airflow deflector still doesn't change.  It is stuck on floor.  It sounds like the module is trying to change, but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you move it with your hand or a long stick? Sometimes those thing jam.

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to mind,  the blend door motor seized while trying to home (not that uncommon an occurrence after disconnecting the battery or if it dies) or you need to home the controller/motor. The homing /calibration is as follows:

- set the temp controls to a little over 1/2
- set the fan on medium (3)
- turn the ignition off
- remove the HVAC fuse or disconnect the battery for 1 minute
- remove the HVAC fuse or disconnect the battery for 1 minute
- install the fuse or reconnect the battery
- start the engine
- let it idle for 2 minutes
- turn off the ignition for at least 10 seconds but no more than 30
- restart the engine and test the a/c controls